# jdbc sql error: statement did not return a result set

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have two stored procedures as follows:

```
create stored procedure p1
as
    select * from table1 where datediff(day, table1.[date], getdate())

create stored procedure p2
as
   declare @t1 table(
     ref varchar(20)
   )
      insert into @t1 select * from table1 where ref = 'some ref'
      declare @t2 table(
      fname varchar(20),
      lname varchar(20),
      email varchar(1000)
  )
  declare @len int = (select count(ref) from @t1)
  while @len > 0
  begin
  declare @value varchar(20)  = (select top 1 ref from @t1)
  insert into @t2 select * from table2 where ref = @ref
  delete from @t1
  where ref = @value
  set @len = (select count(ref) from @t1)
  end
  select * from @t2
```

Java code

```
 ....
 String query = "Execute [p2]";

 try(CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall(query);
     ResultSet rs = cstmt.executeQuery()){
        ... some code
    }
```

The table variable @t1 hold select result from a table 'table1'

The variable @len hold the number of rows in @t1

Using `@len > 0` as condition in while loop, I want to select records from  another table 'table2' the table variable @t2 hold the select records from 'table2'

The delete statement removes value from @t1
@len set to new number of rows in @t1
the last statement return all the records store in @t2

The first procedure works fine, but the second procedure works only in SQL Server.

I get this an error message in my java application

> statement did not return a resultset

I want this to return a result set with the select statement I have at the
end of the query.

Please is there a way around this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your [p2] stored procedure needs to include `SET NOCOUNT ON` right at the beginning to suppress the "*n* rows affected" counts so JDBC doesn't get confused as to what it should put into the ResultSet:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE p2
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @t1 table(
    ref varchar(20)
)

-- ... and so on
```

For more information on SET NOCOUNT see

[SET NOCOUNT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

For more information on precisely what gets returned from a stored procedure call, see

[How to get *everything* back from a stored procedure using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42169951/2144390)

Comment: For anyone who got the error: "org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: The statement did not return a result set." from PDI this answer also resolves that problem when using JDBC(Native) driver.

Answer (score 2):

use method "execute" instead of "executeQuery".