# Executing a Stored Procedure using CallableStatement returns no ResultSet

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have the following SQL Server stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM MyTable
END
```

When I run this procedure using SSMS it returns a result. However, when I call this stored procedure from Java code using `CallableStatement` it does not returning any result and throws the exception

> Statement did not return any ResultSet

**Update 1:**

My Java code is

```java
String sql = "{ call MyProc };";
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(sql);
ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Can you show me how your code looks? One more thing you add SET NOCOUNT ON; before select statement.

Comment: @Mo.Ashfaq can you try to change `String sql = "{ call MyProc };";
` to `String sql = "{ call MyProc() };";`

Comment: @Jens tried this also String sql = "{ call MyProc() };"; but no result

Comment: @Mo.Ashfaq maybe you have to specify the out parameter.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion of Paresh? Otherwise use `execute` and `getMoreResults` and either get an update count or result set (based on the boolean return value).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jdbc sql error: statement did not return a result set](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24428928/2144390)